# Convert group column month int into full name

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a column group of month integers that look like this:

```
1  |  2  |  3  |  etc... |
--------------------------
```

How can I convert this into the month name like this:

```
January | February | March | etc... |
-------------------------------------
```

I have clicked on the Column Group and changed the expression to this:

```
=MonthName(Fields!CREATED_MONTH.Value)
```

But is still showing up as integers... Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the Syntax is:

`=MonthName(Month(Fields!CREATED_MONTH.Value)`

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: It seems to return `#Error`. `Conversion from type 'Integer' to type 'Date' is not valid` would you have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What is the value type of `Fields!CREATED_MONTH.Value` is it an int type? If so would it not work to convert the int type into a date `MonthName(Month(CDate(Fields!CREATED_MONTH.Value)))`

Comment: It was a varchar and i was able to achieve it with `MonthName(Fields!CREATED_MONTH.Value)`. Thank you for the help though.